# PyStemmer: ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: python, dll, python-import, dllimport, importerror

I'm using the Python package Bag of Words, `bow.py` (https://github.com/dmiro/bagofwords/blob/master/bow.py).

Basically I'm running the command:

```
dc = bow.DefaultDocument()
dc.read_text("paragraph string here")
```

I get the following trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bag_of_words.py", line 93, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "bag_of_words.py", line 27, in main
    bag_of_words_classifier_test("item", "category_1", "category_2")
  File "bag_of_words.py", line 73, in bag_of_words_classifier_test
    dc.read_text("paragraph string here")
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bow.py", line 339, in read_text
    self._read(None, text)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bow.py", line 326, in _read
    words = self.tokenizer(text)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bow.py", line 306, in tokenizer
    words = self.after_tokenizer(WordFilters, words)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bow.py", line 517, in after_tokenizer
    words = wordfilters.stemming(self.lang, self.stemming, words)
  File "C:\Users\User Name\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bow.py", line 250, in stemming
    import Stemmer as stemmer
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

I thought it might be an issue with PyStemmer, so I tried forcing a pip3 reinstall/upgrade but got the same error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this doesn't really solve the problem, but it is a work-around:

If you open `bow.py` you can replace line 250 with `import snowballstemmer as stemmer` (instead of `import Stemmer as stemmer`) and then replace line 252 with `stemmer = stemmer.stemmer(lang)` (instead of `stemmer = stemmer.Stemmer(lang)`). The equivalent methods just require a change from uppercase to lowercase.